# Social media notification integration to our website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, instagram-api, facebook-social-plugins

Following are my requirements

1. created space in website that user can come and sign up with FB or Instagram to integrate their account
2. Through Graph API for FB and API for Instagram, I can able to view and post the images to FB (post is not possible to instagram)
3. My requirement would be **any activities (like and share ) happened at the FB or Instagram page should receives as notification to my website**

I came to know there is no direct APIs available to achieving notifications but I have seen them in "Social Stream" app.

any help would be appreciated on how could achieve this functionality

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can get likes, comments and posts using API. You can poll them at regular interval, compare new data and create your own notifications.

(You have to get your app approved by Instagram to get API permissions, which may be possible for your usecase, if you do get approval, then its possible to achieve what you are trying to do.)